# jQuery Flexigrid Resize columns in IE7 broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In firefox, column resizing works fine. But in ie7, it's broken.

[Here's a thread](http://markmail.org/message/dyv44u5fjhgylu2r?q=ie7+resize+column+list:com.googlegroups.flexigrid) about flexigrid broken from jquery 1.3, I've tried the suggested edits to the flexigrid code, didnt work.

We're currently using jquery 1.3, although i've tried 1.3.1 & 1.3.2, neither fixed the problem.

While inspecting the css in ie7, I noticed `<div class="cDrag">` (the div that contains the styles for dragging columns) was way to the right of my grid.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 requires the following at the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http:// www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```